# Numbering of Tables and Figure in Latex without chapter numbers (continuous) and separate from each other

Tags: tables, floats, numbering, report

In the document class `report` the standard way of numbering tables and figures is with the chapter number in front so 1.1, 1.2, 2.1 etc. I managed to remove the chapter number to get a continuous numbering (1, 2, 3, ...) using

```
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
```

However, now I get Figure 1 and then Table 2 and Table 3, but I would like it to be Table 1 and Table 2, so each float is continuous but separate from each other.

How can I achieve that please?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Could you edit your code to begin with your `\documentclass{}` and end with `\end{document}` , a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please. It makes copy and pasting easier when the code can be compiled and also we do not need to guess what commands or packages you are using.

Comment: by default the code you show will do what you want, so there must be more code you have not shown